# Issue with deploying geodjango on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, geodjango

I made a simple GIS application with GeoDjango and I am struggling to deploy it on Heroku. I tried with Heroku-18 stack with heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1 but it got [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config' error. I also tried heroku-16 with  https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git buildpack but ended up with getting this error ImportError: libjasper.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. My requirements.txt is as below:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
django==2.1.4
gdal==2.1.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.7
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
pytz==2018.7
requests==2.20.1
urllib3==1.24.1
whitenoise==4.1.2
wikipedia==1.4.0
```

I am also using python 3.7.0. Can you please help me?

Comment: my issue resolved! I uninstalled gdal from my env . Then it worked like a charm.

Comment: Hello Biswajit,  Can you please provide the details of your solution.  I don't understand what you mean by you uninstalled gdal from my environment.  You simply removed the gdal==2.1.3 line from requirements.txt file?

Comment: Right. Gdal is no longer needed to be installed separately as it is installed as a part of Django. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Biswajit.  Two questions: 1.  Which Heroku stack are you using Heroku-18?  2.  Are there any environment variables related to gdal or geo that you are setting?  How are you accounting for that?

Comment: Can you share a bare bones app as a git repository on Github?  If not a short note on the configuration as github gist would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your resolution here is right. Here's why:

Heroku-18 stack has GDAL installed, yes... but it doesn't install a version which is *built against python bindings*. This is OK for django, which uses the libraries directly, rather than via a python binding. However, installing gdal directly with pip requires a version that has python bindings.